# Should I ask about the status of my PhD application?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application

I applied for admission for a PhD at a university in the US in mid December.  After contacting a potential advisor, he told me that he is interested in my CV. However, I didn't get any response about the status of my application. So, should I send an email to the professor asking him about the decision of my application or should I contact the university directly?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "status of application"? You mention that you have been offered admission. So, what is this application about?

Comment: M.F., if I misinterpreted what you are asking, please edit your question and do a "rollback."

Answer (score -1):

It's usually the university that handled admissions. Your professor may not have any clue which stage your application is in. So your best bet is contacting the university graduate research department, and asking for timeframes around outcome.

Comment: In the US, graduate admissions are normally handled at the department level, not by the university.   The professor may still not know the status of your application, but they will know how to ask.

Comment: We are speaking of different jurisdictions then. I guess the asker would have the intellect to understand that it's whoever managing the admissions. The university would anyway refer him to the department.